# Who is the "evil Batman" in Injustice 2?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, injustice

In *Injustice 2* #3, Batman is outmatched by another Batman (which carries two Submachine guns). In the latest edition (#34), this Batman is seen talking with Ra's al Ghul and Solovar.

Who is this evil Batman?

Comment: Since the Injustice 2 comics haven't all been released yet, it's very likely that this will be revealed in a later issue, and as such this question violates the "Future Works" policy.

Comment: Oops sorry, I didn't know that. So I re-read Injustice 2 from beginning, and indeed there origin of this Batman is not mentioned yet. Guess I'll just speculate :)

Comment: I've been informed that the answer to this question is revealed in #46, which indeed [seems to be the case](http://www.fandompost.com/2018/02/22/injustice-2-46-review/). So I'm reopening it as it no longer falls under the Future Works policy.

Answer (score 6):

In [Issue #46 of *Injustice 2*](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/injustice-2-46-thinking-smaller/4000-660418/) the fake Batman is revealed to be Jason Todd aka Red Hood.

[image: "Batman" is asked to reveal themselves]

[image: Jason is revealed]

Comment: So badass, he wears a mask *under* his mask.

Comment: @Irishpanda I know right! Here's to hoping he has contact lenses in or something to further the level of badass.

Comment: Looks like he's developing a case of Liefeld-face though. I think they make a cream for that.

Comment: @Irishpanda That's why his eyes glow red

Comment: @Irishpanda a bit late, but this might interest you. Basically explains why the mask under the (sometimes red) hood :)

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8jJn.jpg

Answer (score 5):

In *Injustice 2* #46 it is revealed that this is a certain Jason. The familiar dialogue he has with Damian makes me think that this is indeed Jason Todd. Since he was revived with the Lazarus Pit, this would explain his connection with Ra's. Interesting enough however, he has now a bit white hair like [Jason Blood](http://injustice.wikia.com/wiki/Jason_Blood) who was killed by Spectre in *Injustice Year 3*.